# SharePoint 2007 Web-application is getting crashed due to memory leak

Tags: 2007, administration, performance, database, import

We decided to duplicate an existing web-application (for Podcasting kit), which has site collection only at root level, so created a new web-application (in the same DB instance) and imported (stsadm –o import) the site collection from the existing web-application, did the required configuration changes however did not touch the code.

Now, the duplicate web-application is up and functioning as expected however we are facing a potential performance issue, it throws “Unable to connect to the Database” exception every now and then and I found more than 100 heaps are created while processing the request and w3wp.exe is getting crashed.

We do not have any performance issues with the existing web-application however it is also getting crashed (share the same Database Instance) due to the bad performance of the new web-application.

I could not find any clue to fix this, any clues.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? Is there an answer you can add to this question?

Comment: Can you create an answer with what you did to resolve your issue, and mark it as the "accepted" answer?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an application pool resource issue to me.

It could be that the app pools recycling settings needs to be adjusted, or that the Web server was simply starved of physical memory (which would explain the crashes).

Anyway, glad to hear that moving to a new environment resolved the problem. It would be useful to know whether the new environment is different in any way, e.g. 64-bit or more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

This question has lingered here for a while, hopefully it was solved.

There is not really enough information here yet.  There is no mention regarding any of the logs.  You need to set up some perfmon counters and see if you can find some correlating events.

I would also run SPDIAG and see if it catches anything.

Comment: We were not able to find much out it. The issue has been resolved after we migrated the contents to the new environment..

Comment: Not really an answer. If you need further info, post this as comment please